# Simplify the looping under two sets of conditions

Tags: matlab, loops, controls, indices

I want to establish a pair of indices =`[row col]` where

`row = 4 * (n-1) + i` and `col = 4 * (m-1) + i`

Explanation for `i`, `m` and `n`:

For `n = 1` and `m = 2, 3, 4`, loop `i = 1 : 4`.

For `n = 2` and `m = 1`, loop `i = 1 : 4`.

For `n = 3` and `m = 5`, loop `i = 1 : 4`.

The outcome should be:

`row = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]`

`col = [5 9 13 6 10 14 7 11 15 8 12 16 1 2 3 4 17 18 19 20]`

That is, I want to establish pairs of indices under different sets of `n-m` conditions.

---

My trial:

```
row = []; col = [];
n = 1;
for i = 1 : 4
   for m = [2 3 4]
      row = [row 4 * (n - 1) + i];
      col = [col 4 * (m - 1) + i];
   end
end

n = 2; m = 1;
for i = 1 : 4
   row = [row 4 * (n - 1) + i];
   col = [col 4 * (m - 1) + i];
end

n= 3; m = 5;
for i = 1 : 4
   row = [row 4 * (n - 1) + i];
   col = [col 4 * (m - 1) + i];
end
```

This works but indeed I have many `n-m` conditions and the looping for `i = 1 : 4` appeared repeatedly which seems that can be simplified.

May I know if there are any elegant solutions to finish my objective?

I appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) based solution for all those three cases -

```
ii = 1:4
row = reshape(bsxfun(@(A,B) 4 * (B-1) + A,ii,n'),1,[])  %//'
col = reshape(bsxfun(@(A,B) 4 * (B-1) + A,ii,m'),1,[])  %//'
```

The inputs would be as listed next.

Case #1:

```
m = [2, 3, 4]
n = ones(1,numel(m))
```

Case #2:

```
n = 2
m = 1
```

Case #3:

```
n = 3
m = 5
```

Comment: Thanks. May I know how to combine the three cases to produce only
`row = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]` and `col = [5 9 13 6 10 14 7 11 15 8 12 16 1 2 3 4 17 18 19 20]`.

Comment: @nam Assuming the outputs from these cases as `out1`, `out2` and `out3`, you could do: `[out1 out2 out3]`?

Comment: I got your idea of combining three cases and the use of `bsxfun`. For another issue, would you think that it is also feasible by adding constraints (nested loop?) to the loops (`i  = 1 : 4`) to achieve the purpose?

Comment: @nam Would depend on the constraints themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Matrix with all parameters, then apply the math once:

```
M=[...n           m           i
      ones(3,1)   (2:4).'     (1:3).';...
      2*ones(4,1) ones(4,1)   (1:4).';...
      3*ones(4,1) 5*ones(4,1) (1:4).';...
];

row = (4 * (M(:,1) - 1) + M(:,3)).';
col = (4 * (M(:,2) - 1) + M(:,3)).';
%alternative:
%index=(4 * (M(:,[1:2]) - 1) + M(:,[3,3])).'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help too.